# How to apply manipulate to two objects?

Tags: manipulate

In the output of this code the rectangles and the grid are put between [] and {}. How to get rid of them? I want Manipulate to apply to two objects: the grid and the graphic.

```
PosH = (1 - pH) (1 - kans);
PosI = pI kans;
NegH = pH (1 - kans);
NegI = (1 - pI) kans;

{{PosH, PosI, PosH + PosI}, {NegH, NegI, NegH + NegI}, {PosH + NegH, 
   PosI + NegI, 1}};
Prepend[%, {"Gezond", "Ziek", ""}];
data = MapThread[Prepend, {%, {"", "Positief", "Negatief", ""}}];

Manipulate[
 Grid[
  {AccountingForm[Grid[%, Frame -> All], {3, 3}]},
  {Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1 - kans, pH}], Blue, 
     Rectangle[{1 - kans, 0}, {1, 1 - pI}], Green, 
     Rectangle[{0, pH}, {1 - kans, 1}], Purple, 
     Rectangle[{1 - kans, 1 - pI}, {1, 1}]}]}
  ],
 {{kans, 0.0001}, 0, 1}, {{pI, 0.99}, 0, 1}, {{pH, 0.99}, 0, 1}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display the grid and graphic together using [`Column`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Column.html) :

```
Manipulate[Column[{
   AccountingForm[Grid[%, Frame -> All], {3, 3}], 
   Graphics[{Red, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {1 - kans, pH}], Blue, 
     Rectangle[{1 - kans, 0}, {1, 1 - pI}], Green, 
     Rectangle[{0, pH}, {1 - kans, 1}], Purple, 
     Rectangle[{1 - kans, 1 - pI}, {1, 1}]}]
   }],
 {{kans, 0.0001}, 0, 1}, {{pI, 0.99}, 0, 1}, {{pH, 0.99}, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're looking for -- perhaps this is it.  If not, please clarify what exactly you want the output to be.